# Css link keeps changing when trying to create automated tests

Tags: css, automated-tests, robotframework

I am very new to test automation and I've been sitting here googling for a while but I still can't find an answer to this.

Just a few days ago I decided that I would try to learn test automation through robot framework.

I created a very easy script, in Pycharm, that searches for a product on amazon.com and then adds it to the customers basket and everything worked fine. Then I ran the script a second time and it didn't work. After some research I found out that the Css tag on the product had changed. I copied the tag and pasted it instead of my old one and ran the test again and it worked.

My problem is that the tag seems to be changing even though my code stays the same (except for changing the Css tag).

The code looks like this:
PS: The second "#click link" is a comment and it's either this comment or the link before this that I have to use.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and why the Css is changing whenever I run the code?

```
Begin web test
    open browser  about:blank  chrome
    maximize browser window

Search for products
    go to  http://www.amazon.com
    wait until page contains  Your Amazon.com
    input text  id=twotabsearchtextbox  Ferrari 458
    click button  css=#nav-search > form > div.nav-right > div > input
    click link  css=#result_0 > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > a
    #click link  css=#result_0 > div > div > div > div.a-fixed-left-grid-col.a-col-right > div.a-row.a-spacing-small > a


Add product to shopping cart
    click button  xpath=//*[@id="add-to-cart-button"]
    click link  css=#hlb-ptc-btn-native

End web test
    sleep  10s
    close browser
```

Comment: the css is probably changing because Amazon wants it to change. There is nothing you can do, other than to use some other method to select the element.

Comment: can you please proved what does this line supposed to do? `click button  css=#nav-search > form > div.nav-right > div > input` this is the search button at the end of the search input field at the top of the site?